# Make a hemisphere/dome from flat segments?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Rewritten version after testing (with thanks for all suggestions so far).

Here's the partial solution of what I'm trying to do in blender 2.8:
[image: PARTIAL solution using cloth]
This is a slowly collapsing version of the more solid/crisp effect I'm hoping to produce and has been made with the cloth modifier on with structural and bend settings around 400.

The initial shape is shown as follows and should be producing a rather pointed 'dome' effect, as per the picture.
[image: Panel segment in Blender 'object' and 'edit' modes with CONCEPTUAL dome shown beneath]

**The segments have to curve to an apex *and* fit together perfectly.**

Here's my starting point for the above cloth sim version.
[image: Possible Starting Point]

Can anybody suggest a method of convincing Blender to curve two planes (up to a total of six for the full 'dome') so that they fit together along an edge, bending to accommodate the curve and without flapping all over the place as per the cloth sim?

I do understand that there are other ways of creating a similar shape, but the first prize is using the above idea.

Edit: The [Domed tent example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41982/how-to-model-a-dome-tent?rq=1) is very similar in effect needed, but how to ensure the panel form is simply bent, not stretched?

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IrfYco01z7Xw9JWj1uZFmHe423meHIrt)

Comment: could you please show your current topology so that it's easier to understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a rounded cone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90963/how-to-create-a-rounded-cone)

Comment: Nothing like the rounded cone solution, I'm afraid – interesting, though. Images following...

Comment: I would think all you need to do is use the screw modifier, no?

Comment: @Coffeehouse Check the new image I've added above which shows six of the panels standing vertically.  I want to achieve an effect where the panels bend inwards together, joining along the long, curved edges. 

The screw modifier produces some amazing effects with this piece, though, even if it's not what I'm looking for. If you can do it, tell me, please?

Comment: I have a NASTY partial solution: cloth modifier with gravity turned off. The result is neither crisp nor quick!
See main post for image.

Comment: you could use curve modifier before the array but anyway with this topology the result won't be perfect

Comment: @moonboots It's hard going. I did attempt to run the curve from the shape of the panel edge, but either I'm not that good or the idea was flawed (the former is far more likely at this stage in the game).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this topology is the best to make a dome, but here is a solution:

- Make sure you've applied the scale of your object.
- Shift a bit your mesh from its origin.
- Create a curve which follows approximately the curve you want. Check the direction, put its origin at its bottom.
- Give your mesh a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*.
- Create an empty at the same point as the mesh origin.
- Give your mesh an *Array* modifier, give it a *Count* of 6. Enable *Merge*, choose the *Object Offset* mode with the empty as *Object*.
- Rotate the empty 60° on the Z axis. The object should rotate around the Z axis.
- Shift the mesh a bit so that its bottom stick to its duplications bottom.
- Edit the curve so that the sides of the mesh stick to its duplications.
- Edit the object: Select some horizontal edges and scale a bit with the *Proportional Editing* enabled, so that the vertices of the mesh stick to its duplications.
- Once you're glad you can apply the modifiers and remove the doubles (but keep a copy somewhere).
- You'll have to make some additional editing to clean it a bit, create some nice edges with bevels, and to avoid artefacts. I've also used a <kbd>W</kbd> > *Smooth*. You may want to work only on 1/6 of the dome and re-use an array to duplicate it again.

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh, right!
Not as slick as I'd *hoped* Blender could provide, not as bad as I'd feared the task might be.
Thank you – the topology may not be perfect, but some Victorian designer came up with it and your version looks as good a try as anything without sheets of copper and a batch of solder; as we often say, "It probably seemed like a good idea at the time."

Answer (score 0):

You can actually start with a more blocky version of the dome, like this.
[image: Blocky Version]
Just add a Subdivide modifier (Found in the modifiers tab), and tweak the settings to your heart's content.
[image: Subdiv modifier can be found here]
[image: With it on]
And this is what it looks like as a solid. You can add more subdivisions and turn on smooth shading for a better look.
[image: Final product]

EDIT: I'm using Blender 2.79b (sorry, haven't started in 2.80 yet), but the same steps apply in all versions, including 2.80.

Comment: Hm.
How do I ensure that the form of the panel is maintained/achieved? The spec is for the shape 'as above' and I could spend a very happy time guessing at what might fit, but I'm hoping for a This Does Fit. Imagine the shape cut out in paper six times and taped together along the long edges.

No worries with the Blender version, I'm fairly sure this is achievable using some sort of juggle between standard functions – curve modifiers and arrays, or whatever.

Comment: Check out the new image I've dropped in above to see the starting point of what I hope to achieve and then imagine bending the panels into the centre of the circle, joining along the curved edges.

Comment: @QuinBenson The image isn't showing up. Your method of "taping" them would work.  You could try shaping a 3D shape to what you need (Simply by having the flat model behind the 3D model and shaping the 3D model in Orthographic projection)